# VBA Pass Superscript String to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, format

I want to create ordinal numbers and pass them to Outlook Body in correct format, but when I do so all formatting is gone. How to manage the situation ?
Ordinal numbers are 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.
My code below

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutAppoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutAppoint = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

Cells(1, 1).Value = "2nd"
Cells(1, 1).Characters(2, 3).Font.Superscript = True
Ordinal_number = Cells(1,1).Value

With OutAppoint:
   .Body = Ordinal_number
   .Display
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting will be lost as you noticed. Try as below instead. Those characters will at least survive the copying. Make sure they survive all the way.

The code is using superscript and modifier unicode letters instead.

```
Dim SuperST As String, SuperND As String, SuperRD As String, SuperTH As String
SuperST = ChrW(&H2E2) & ChrW(&H1D57)
SuperND = ChrW(&H207F) & ChrW(&H1D48)
SuperRD = ChrW(&H2B3) & ChrW(&H1D48)
SuperTH = ChrW(&H1D57) & ChrW(&H2B0)
...
Cells(1, 1).Value = "2" & SuperND
'Cells(1, 1).Characters(2, 3).Font.Superscript = True ' No need for this anymore
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. So, it cannot contain any formatting you have set on the excel side. Instead, you can copy the required content in Excel and paste it in the message body using the Word object model or just export everything to the HTML markup in Excel and then set up the `HTMLBody` property in Outlook.

---

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, if it weren't for this Unicode answer I would have to play with HTML body, which would work but would be more time consuming